# Django 4.1 отображение неверного шаблона

Tags: python-3.x, django

Имеется проект на Django 4.1 в котором определены 2 приложения: cart, shop. При обращении к view одного приложения Django пытается рендерить данный шаблон из другого приложения, что приводит к ошибке **TemplateDoesNotExist at /cart/**.
Пути к шаблонам разные, urls разные.

Cart:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'cart'

urlpatterns = [
    path('add/<int:product_id>/', views.cart_add, name='cart_add'),
    path('remove/<int:product_id>/', views.cart_remove, name='cart_remove'),
    path('', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
]
```

Путь до шаблона в cart:
*Internet_shop/myshop/cart/templates/cart/detail.html*

---

Shop:

```
from . import views


app_name = 'shop'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
    path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
    path('', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
]
```

Путь до шаблона в shop:
*Internet_shop/myshop/shop/templates/shop/product/detail.html*

Главный файл urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),
    path('', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
]
```

Непосредственно при вызове из html шаблона cart_add ссылающегося на cart_detail определённом во views приложения cart:

```
@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    """ Adding items to the cart or updating their quantity. """
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'], override_quantity=cd['override'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')

def cart_detail(request):
    """ Template link function for cart_add and cart_remove. """
    cart = Cart(request)
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

Мне возвращает:
Internet_shop/myshop/**shop**/templates/cart/detail.html (Source does not exist)

Пробовал давать разные имена html файлам. Не помогло.

Почему ищет в **shop** если всё определено в **cart**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге с автором разобрались с проблемой.

1. Нужно было добавить пути для TEMPLATES в settings.py:
   `'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']`
2. Соответсвенно назвать папку с темплейтами - «templates»
3. Добавить все приложение в INSTALLED_APPS